# OnSizeAllocated, OnMeasure, InvalidateMeasure in Xamarin Froms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I can't really find any documentation with examples how to correctly override and use OnSizeAllocated, OnMeasure, InvalidateMeasure methods. Can someone give any examples?

As a background I'd like to implement Editor that has a height of 200 when it's empty, but when it's full of text it will grow.

Comment: You know the `Editor` has auto-sizing built-in now? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor#auto-sizing-an-editor

Comment: @Gerald Versluis yes, but it can't be combined with custom height. You can set requested height, OR have auto size. I want to have both.

Comment: Ah, you're right! :)

Comment: You might want to check these two links: 
[Xamarin Forms Layout Engine, Under The Hood](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-layout-engine-hood/)
and
[Hacking the Xamarin.Forms Layout System for Fun and Profit](https://michaelridland.com/xamarin/hacking-the-xamarin-forms-layout-system-for-fun-and-profit/)